# select combobox item by value C#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a combobox , bound to `Datatable` 
and have the following properties:

```
cboCars.DisplayMember = "carLiscen";
cboCars.ValueMember = "carNo";
```

How can I select the `DisplayMember` when I know the `ValueMember` ?

Comment: cant you simply use the combobox.Text property?

Comment: the comboBox.Text property shows me the DisplayMember value. i have the ValueMember.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a `ValueMember` set you can select using `SelectedValue`

```
cboCars.DisplayMember = "carLiscen";
cboCars.ValueMember = "carNo";

cboCars.SelectedValue = "valuemember value";
```

Comment: Why does everyone keep saying this? This doesn't work in a winforms app.

Comment: data type of value should be same as it is in datasource.

Comment: @AbdullahQudeer your comment did the job for me. The `valueMember` of my datasource was `int` but I was casting a `short` value.

Comment: @JonathanWood  It only works if you are mapping a datasource, which I think a lot of people do.  If you add items manually this doesn't seem to work.  Sorry it took me 10 years to reply.

Answer (score 2):

You can search for the correct item and set it to that, very simple:

```
cbTEST.SelectedIndex = cbTEST.FindStringExact("your search string here");
```

or select an item based on an ListViewItem:

```
cbTEST.SelectedIndex = cbTEST.FindStringExact(lvTEST.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text);
```

thats it. very simple!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cboCars.SelectedValue = "123";` property for this. Here's a code snippet which will show it in action.

```
    public void Test()
    {
        ArrayList info = new ArrayList();
        info.Add(new CarInfo { CarLiscen = 123456, CarNo = 123});
        info.Add(new CarInfo { CarLiscen = 234567, CarNo = 234 });
        cboCars.DataSource = info;

        cboCars.DisplayMember = "CarLiscen";
        cboCars.ValueMember = "CarNo";

        cboCars.SelectedValueChanged +=
            delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (cboCars.SelectedIndex != -1)
                {
                    this.Text = cboCars.SelectedValue.ToString();
                }
            };

        cboCars.SelectedValue = 234;
    }
```

And if you wonder what is the definition of `CarInfo`. Here's its code (which is fairly simple):

```
public class CarInfo
{
    public int CarLiscen { get; set; }
    public int CarNo { get; set; }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Guys the best way if searching for a text or value
is

```
int Selected;    
int count = ComboBox1.Items.Count;
    for (int i = 0; (i<= (count - 1)); i++) 
     {        
         ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = i;
        if ((string)(ComboBox1.SelectedValue) == "SearchValue") 
        {
            Selected = i;
        }

    }

    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = Selected;
```

Comment: Working but this is not a proper way, cause it might get slow operation on Large volume of data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the combobox expect the exact type.
So if you for example use a datagridview and you see the value (int) in the field, you pass it to the SelectedValue property of the combo. But in fact you are not passing an integer, you are passing an object. That is what usually is going wrong. It my a while to sort this out, but finally I have found how to do it...
How to solve this... easy:

For example, you have an ID (integer in the database), then you need to do something like this:

This is the one that I did and it does not work:
cmbFilter.SelectedValue = dgvListOfFilters.Rows[intRowSelected].Cells[3].Value;

You should do this to make it work:
int intCategory = Convert.ToInt32(dgvListOfFilters.Rows[intRowSelected].Cells[3].Value);
cmbFilter.SelectedValue = intCategory;

Hope this will be helpfull for many people...